# Passing information to a constructor without using a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I have backed myself into a a bit of a corner.  Here is a simplified version of what I have (in C#):

```
class OuterClass
{
    private class BadClass
    {
        private int Data;

        public BadClass()
        {
            Data = 0;

            ...
        }
    }

    T Build<T>(Object Input)
    {
        T x = new T();
        ...
        return x;
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        BadClass a = Build<BadClass>(anObject);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem I have is that I now must change the initial value of Data depending on the instance of OuterClass that is creating the BadClass instance.  Normally I would simply use a BadClass constructor that takes a parameter:

```
public BadClass(int Data)
{
    this.Data = Data;
    ...
}
```

But I use BadClass in several generic types so I must have a parameterless BadClass constructor.  Too bad I can't do something like this:

```
Build<BadClass(5)>(anObject);
```

So, how do I give a constructor run-time information when I can't pass parameters into the constructor?
Is it possible to create a runtime instance of a BadClass type, give it the information it needs, and then use that in my generic types?

**EDIT:** I used List as an example generic type but that didn't fully express the depth of my dilemma...
I can create a test in Build to call an init function if I am working with a BadClass, but that is very hacky.  I am hoping to find a slightly less ugly way to go about it.

Comment: Why not overload the constructor?

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. The fact that you're passing an object to the Build method smells very fishy to me. Is there some pattern you're trying to implement?

Comment: This is a simplified version.  I am just trying to explain the constraints I am working with.  
It is a modified factory pattern.  I have several classes that have the same base class. I use the factory (Build above) to generate the proper instance of a class.  
It is obviously more complex than what I show here.  The Object that is passed into the factory is a node in a binary tree, the factory determines where the BadClass should be inserted into the tree and does some other stuff.  There are several different factory functions.  I can use a two stage constructor, but it will be ugly.

Comment: I thought I was being cute when I originally wrote it.  Obviously it was a bit too cute, and now I am paying for it...

Comment: I have to hope that your actual code better represents your intent. I also hope you'll soon learn the Single Responsibility Principal, which basically says your factory should not both be creating an instance and deciding where it belongs in a tree, along with "some other stuff".

Comment: Yea, I think I have been clear that my original design was bad.   Thanks for making me jump through hoops to prove I really need an answer to the question I asked and then being incapable of answering it.

Comment: I don't think you've shown you need an answer to this question. I think you've proven you've designed yourself into a corner. Best bet: get out of the corner.

Comment: Um, yea, that is why the first sentance of my question was: "I have backed myself into a a bit of a corner."  I'm not going to start a flame war here.  If you really feel the need to continue this conversation you can e-mail me at: DICK <That character you know> jasek <dot> org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have multiple BadClass types that are variations of generics, you can do so by changing your inheritance tree:

```
class OuterClass {
    private class BadClassBase {
        // whatever BadClass does 
    }
    private class BadClass : BadClassBase {
        public BadClass(T item) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're going for but you can then create your List<BadClassBase>.

Comment: This is close to what I needed.  It works great as long as data has a limited number of valid values.  I removed the parameter-less constructor for BadClass and created multiple inherited classes.  So I have BadClass1, BadClass2, etc where their base class is BadClass.  Theses classes only contain a single constructor that looks like: public BadClass1() : base(1) { }

Answer (score 6):

When you create the `List<BadClass>`, you are not creating any BadClass instances. Go ahead and create a that way, but when you create a BadClass instance to add to it, that's when you call your parameterized constructor:

```
List<BadClass> a = new List<BadClass>();
a.Add(new BadClass(1));
a.Add(new BadClass(2));
```

By the way, having the construction of a BadClass instance depend on which OuterClass is creating it is a bit of a code smell. What you you trying to accomplish?

Comment: And why would you not be able to have multiple constructors? ;D
'But I use BadClass in several generic types so I must have a parameterless BadClass constructor' got me confused.

Comment: List was a bad example, a generic type can definitely create an instance of BadClass in it's constructor. I could probably work around this way, but I think my code would smell worse if I had a parameter-less constructor that should never be used.  
Also, when I originally coded BadClass I did not foresee the need to adjust Data, obviously I screwed up

Comment: wtaniguchi - I can have multiple constructors, but using the class in a generic type means I MUST have a constructor with no parameters. I can no longer build a valid parameter-less constructor.

Comment: @oillio: I think you're confused about when an instance of BadClass will be created. There is no operation on the list that will ever create an instance of BadClass. Are you maybe thinking about serialization?

Comment: @John - Check out my edit.  Does that better detail my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give BadClass an initialization method?

```
private class BadClass
{
    private int Data;

    public BadClass()
    {
        Data = 0;
        ...
    }

    public void Init(int dataValue)
    {
        Data = dataValue;
    }
}
```

Then when you create one it is:

```
BadClass myInst = new BadClass(); // void constructor, as you require.
myInst.Init(5);  // Set the value to 5.
```

Comment: +1, I like this pattern -- it's called "two-phase construction" in (some of) the literature, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like that?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class OuterClass
{
    private class BadClass
    {
        private int _data;

        public BadClass()
        {
            _data = 0;

        }

        public int Data
        {
          get
          {
             return _data;
          }
          set
          {
             _data = value;
          }
        }

    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        List<BadClass> a = new List<BadClass>() 
        { 
          new BadClass() { Data = 7 }, 
          new BadClass() { Data = 9 } 
        };
    }
}
```